# Safelist all margin values with screen variants in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, css-purge

I need to safelist all margin values with the respective responsive sizes.

Example:

- 'mb-10'
- 'md:mb-10'
- 'xl:mb-10'

and so on.

Here is what I have right now in my `tailwind.config.js` but it doesn't seem to work for the **responseive** variants:

```
safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /\-?m(\w?)-/,
    },
],
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this with regex patterns or do I need any other specific configuration? I would of course like to avoid listing them all manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I would like to preface this by saying that this behavior is not recommended if this is meant for a production site. Tailwind docs explicitly state safelisting is a last ditch effort. The file produced by this safelisting alone would be upwards of 80kb.

That said, the part you're missing for responsive variants is the variants option [as stated in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20force%20Tailwind%20to%20generate%20variants%20for%20any%20matched%20classes%2C%20include%20them%20using%20the%20variants%20option%3A). But your regex pattern would also be grabbing more than just margin utilities.

In order to prevent the inclusion of other classes that contain `m-` (`bottom-` and `scroll-m-`) you can add them in a non-capturing group before looking for the margin string.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^(?!(?:scroll|bottom)$)m\w?-/,
      variants: ['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', '2xl'],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I had tried using `variants` but for some reason it didn't seem to work, maybe my `pattern` was wrong. That said I'm fully aware that this behaviour should be avoided, but I need this exceptionally in a project for the time being, hopefully I'll be able to solve this in some other way to avoid this malpractice. In the meantime I thank you for your help!

Comment: The pattern `/^(?!(?:scroll|bottom)$)m\w?-/` does not work for multiple reason, one being that it only works for new lines `^`. Also, you need a negative lookbehind instead of negative lookahead. This pattern is tested and works... `/(?<!scroll-|botto)m\w?-/`.

Comment: warn - The safelist pattern `/^(?!(?:scroll|bottom)$)m\w?-/` doesn't match any Tailwind CSS classes.